# Ajax mysql query based on link text with multiple links on page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have some links on a page. When a user clicks a link, it uses the text from the link in the `WHERE` clause of the mysql query and returns the result to the page using ajax.

I need multiple ids or classes to run the different queries. I've tried `querySelectorAll` with multiple ids (see below) and also `getElementsByClassName()` with multiple classes but the query returns undefined in the `WHERE` clause for both of these.

I can get it to work on one link using `getElementById` though.

What am I doing wrong?

Html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a id="spquery" onclick='ajaxFunction()'>John</a></li>
    <li><a id="spquery1" onclick='ajaxFunction()'>Jill</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='ajaxDiv'>Results will display here</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script languspquery="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
 var ajaxRequest; 

 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
     ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }catch (e){
     // Something went wrong
     alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }

 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
 }
// below you can see I'm using querySelectorAll with multiple ids
 var spquery = document.querySelectorAll('#spquery, #spquery1').text;
 var queryString = "?spquery=" + spquery ;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/the-bootstrap/ajax-ped.php" + queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
```

The mysql query from /the-bootstrap/ajax-ped.php

```
$spquery = $_GET['spquery'];
$query = "SELECT * from people";
$query .= " WHERE personname = '$spquery'";
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` will return an array of nodes. To use the value of each of the nodes you need to iterate the array like this

```
var arr_spquery = document.querySelectorAll('#spquery,#spquery1');
var spquery = '', sep='';
for(var i=0,len=arr_spquery.length; i<len; i++) {
spquery += sep + arr_spquery[i].innerHTML;
sep = ',';
}
console.log(spquery);  /* optional - to log the value */

var queryString = "?spquery=" + spquery ;
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "/the-bootstrap/ajax-ped.php" + queryString, true);
ajaxRequest.send(null);
```

Then on the server side in php script you can use the string as you want. :)